# Export out of Order Update LR CC 5.4

Tags: error, export, albums

Lightroom, having updated to 5.4, exports my albums in with a random photo order. I can't find a setting to change this.
Is there a workaround available? Or can this be fixed somehow?

Thanks.

Windows 10, Lenovo Legion, LR CC 5.4

Comment: Do you see randomness in small batches (between 3-4 consecutive photos) or it is for example 1st photo, then last photo and so on?

Comment: And have you consider update to 5.7? AFAIK if you have 5.4 you can for free update to latest 5.x version.

Comment: It says my 5.4 is up to date. I'll be updating as soon as it's available on my CC.

Comment: It seems to be entirely random, regardless of album size.

Comment: My mistake, I did not get CC. Are you sure the images on main screen are sorted properly?

Comment: Yes. And there is no discernable pattern to the error.